# How to create a Hash in Neo4j from given string?

Tags: hash, neo4j, cypher

I do the following

CREATE (p:person { FirstName:"M", LastName: "H" , Language: "en", hash: apoc.util.sha512('1234567','salt')});

Error:
Function call does not provide the required number of arguments: expected 1 got 2.

Function apoc.util.sha512 has signature: apoc.util.sha512(values :: LIST? OF ANY?) :: STRING?
meaning that it expects 1 argument of type LIST? OF ANY?
Description: apoc.util.sha512([values]) | computes the sha512 of the concatenation of all string values of the list (line 2, column 73 (offset: 73))
"CREATE (p:person { FirstName:"M", LastName: "H" , Language: "en", hash: apoc.util.sha512('1234567','salt')});"

what is a Type of List argument?
thanks rob

Answer (score 0):

Have it - i used []

CREATE (p:person { FirstName:"M", LastName: "H" , Language: "de", hash: apoc.util.sha512(**[**"1234567","salt"**]**)});